# Values for entries of a matrix to have full row rank.

Tags: matrices

We are given the following matrix:
$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        b_1 &  \lambda_1b_1 & \lambda_1^2b_1 & \ldots &\lambda_1^{n-1}b_1 \\
         b_2 &  \lambda_2b_2 & \lambda_2^2b_2 & \ldots &\lambda_2^{n-1}b_2\\
        \vdots\\          
        b_n &  \lambda_nb_n & \lambda_n^2b_n & \ldots &\lambda_n^{n-1}b_n \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

For what values of $\lambda_k$ and $b_k\,(k=1,\ldots,n)$ is the rank of $A$ equal to $n$?

How does one solve this and what is the solution?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) for how to type matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(A)=b_1\cdots b_n \det(V)$, where $\det(V)$ is the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix of $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$, so $\det(A)=b_1\cdots b_n \prod\limits_{1\le i< j \le n}(\lambda_j - \lambda_i)$, so if $b_i \neq 0$ and $\lambda_j \neq \lambda_i$ ($i \neq j$), then $A$ is full rank.

Comment: Should it be $A = b_1...b_2det(V)$ or b_n?

Comment: @Deeya it should be $b_n$, edited it.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. :)